# IBM DS5020 SNMP monitoring

Tags: zabbix

I want to monitor the states of IBM DS5020,such as disks,controller.

Anyone successfully monitoring  IBM DS5020 storage systems?

I can't seem to find a way how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation the DS can only send snmp traps, so you can't extract data with standard snmp walks/get.

You can use the SMCli tool, invoke it with system.run and filter the data you need. Or you can build a SMCli + zabbix_send script.

Comment: The SMCli tool is like 'IBM DS Storage Manager'?

Comment: How to use SMCli + zabbix_send script,is there a example?Such as to monitoring controller switching time.

Comment: Afaik there isn't anything readily available. With a google search I've found an old perl script: https://www.zabbix.com/forum/zabbix-help/22816-ibm-ds-3500-3512-3200-snmp-monitoring but you'll need to check it and adapt it to your needs